# What kind of bug is this?

Tags: bug-identification

[image: this is a bug inside my house. I need help identifying what kind of bug this is for peace of mind. Please help]
This is a bug inside my house. I need help identifying what kind of bug this is for peace of mind. Please help

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question like that without knowing where you are. The photo also doesn't give a sense of scale, and size can be an important clue. If you can get photos from other angles that would help as well

Comment: I don't know what that critter is, but I get a lot of large, weird looking insects in my house too (Northern VA), and I try to evict them by putting a small but wide-mouthed jar over them, sliding a piece of stiff paper under the jar, and then releasing them outside.   With a few invasive exceptions, insects do far more to maintain the health of the ecosystems in which they are found, and on which we not-so-indirectly depend, than homo sap does.  I know the OMG! factor is real and strong, but we have the intellect to overcome it.   I hope someone can identify this bug!

Comment: My "Picture Insect" app says it's a 'Flat wireworm beetle'. The photos appear to match up exactly with your example. https://bugguide.net/node/view/1400050/bgimage